# App prints debug strings but no OutputDebugString used

Tags: windows, debuggers

An application I'm reversing frequently outputs debug strings. Some of them could aid me in locating the code I'm looking for, but somehow, the app doesn't seem the be using OutputDebugString at all (I've used IDA's Imports window, Olly's Search for intermodular calls, and `dumpbin /IMPORTS`). The program only imports native Windows DLLs and one custom library which does call the function, but I've checked it and all its debug strings are internal stuff, there's no exported logging function for my exe.

Additionally, the debug strings being printed cannot be found inside the exe (again, tried both Olly and IDA).

Is it possible that the call is somehow hidden by not using WinAPI? Since the program is in no way protected, I find the use of any such techniques highly unlikely, but could that be why I can't find anything using "ordinary" methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ollydbg**

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> -> events -> check mark break on debug string on break

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to view call stack

**WinDbg**

```
sx- -c "kc" out
```

This will print the call stack automatically on each and every DebugString.

```
0:000> g

This is from Win32Api
Going deeper now

kernel32!RaiseException
kernel32!OutputDebugStringA
dbgprints!wmain
dbgprints!__tmainCRTStartup
kernel32!BaseProcessStart
hello from ntdll!DbgPrint 


ntdll!vDbgPrintExWithPrefix
ntdll!DbgPrint
dbgprints!wmain
dbgprints!__tmainCRTStartup
kernel32!BaseProcessStart
(5d8.950): Unknown exception - code eaceba5e (first chance)
This String is from RaiseException argument 1
```

Comment: Found it using *only* OllyDbg and your method - I guess the "Accept" goes to you sir.

Answer (score 2):

Some debuggers can pause the program when it prints a debug message. Then you can go up the stack trace and see whence it is coming.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint on `OutputDebugString()`; when the breakpoint hits, check the callstack to find the source of the call.

> I can't, that's the point - it doesn't seem to be called, yet the
>   strings are output.

Then the strings aren't being output by the executable. Attach WinDbg to your system and set breakpoints on `nt!DbgPrint` and `nt!DbgPrintEx`; when the breakpoint hits, check the callstack to find the source of the call.

Comment: I can't, that's the point - it doesn't seem to be called, yet the strings are output.

Comment: About the edit: that's what I was talking about - thanks :)